# How many sets of numbers can we find?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> We have the following set of numbers $1,2\dots14$.
>
> a) How many subsets with 4 numbers can we find that contain only one even number
>
> b) How many subsets with 4 numbers can we find that have a sum of an even number

As for the a, what I am thinking is , every subset with 3 numbers out of $1,3,5,7,9,11,13 $ is $\binom73=\frac{7!}{3!\cdot4!}=35$

So for every subset that I already have I need  to add one number out of $ 2,4,6,8,10,12,14$ which means I have 7 choices for each subset. Therefore $7\cdot35$

My problem is with b

Comment: For b), there are three cases to consider: 1) four odds, 2) four evens, and 3) two odds and two evens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider the three cases in which four numbers from the set can sum to an even number.

- All numbers are even: $\binom74=35$ ways
- All numbers are odd: 35 ways (there are seven even and seven odd numbers; the situation is symmetric between the four-odd and four-even cases)
- Two numbers are even and two are odd: $\binom72^2=441$ ways

Adding up, we find $35+35+441=511$ admissible subsets.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of numbers is even when we have even numbers of odds!

Here we can have $4$ odds (**and** no evens), $2$ odds (**and** $2$ evens), and $0$ odds (**and** $4$ evens) to let the sum of numbers be even. $\underline{\text{And}}$ means multiplication.

So we have:

$$\displaystyle{7 \choose 4}{7 \choose 0}+{7 \choose 2}{7 \choose 2}+{7 \choose 0}{7 \choose 4}$$

Comment: Nice answer.  However, you meant to say multiplication.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for your comment and excuse my typo, I edited it.